# How to read field name with space in Json using OPENJSON in SQL Server 2016

Tags: json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

How can I read value from json file in that field name contains space using **OPENJSON** in **Sql Server 2016**. See the below code:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json = N'{ "full name" : "Jayesh Tank"}';
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH ( [name] [varchar](60) '$.full name')
```

Also another sample code in that space is after field name.

```
SET @json = N'{ "name   " : "abc"}';
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH ( [name] [varchar](60)    '$.name')
```

`'$.name'` will return null.Is there way to read this value?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally it is a bad idea to use spaces in the attribute name.

I would leave out the `[` `]` from your OPENJSON name and varchar(60) - source MSDN [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql).

Now to actually answer your question:

You need to format your attribute with double quotes in the `WITH` clause:

```
@DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json=N'{ "full name" : "Jayesh Tank"}';
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (name varchar(60) '$."full name"')
```

for the second one:

```
SET @json = N'{ "name   " : "abc"}';
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH ( name varchar(60)'$."name   "')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON_VALUE(c.value,'$.Serial Number') as [Serial Number] is throwing an error with a space. How do I resolve the space in the field name using JSON_VALUE .

by itself '$.Full Name' is not a valid json, but adding '$."Full Name"' the json becomes valid
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this says using OPENJSON, but Googling JSON_VALUE led me here. To get the value using JSON_VALUE for a key that has a space, don't do this:

```
 JSON_VALUE([Data], '$.Your Name') AS [Name]
```

Put the value in double quotes, like this:

```
 JSON_VALUE([Data], '$."Your Name"') AS [Name]
```

and it will work.

Comment: I am getting: 
Msg 13609, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'T' is found at position 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a space in the JSON tag, use double quotes inside the single quotes and the JSON tag is case sensitive

```
 SELECT *  FROM OPENJSON(@json)  WITH (   
        InjectionPoint nvarchar(max) '$."injection Point"',
        tanksize nvarchar(max) '$."tank Size"',
        TargetUsage nvarchar(max) '$."target Usage"',
        TargetAllowance nvarchar(max) '$."target Allowance"',
        PriceGal nvarchar(max) '$."price/Gal"',
        TankLocationId nvarchar(max) '$."tank Location ID"',
        SrAcctMgr nvarchar(max) '$."sr ACCT MGR"',
        District nvarchar(max) '$.district',
        County nvarchar(max) '$.county',
        LiftMechanism nvarchar(max) '$."lift Mechanism"',
        opRegion nvarchar(max) '$.opRegion',
        area nvarchar(max) '$.area',
        u_id nvarchar(max) '$.u_ID'
 
) as JSON
```