# Using OPENJSON in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, open-json

I'm trying to pull some information from a JSON array stored in an SQL Server database. I can see I need to use OPENJSON, and I've found numerous examples of how to use it, but the rub is all of the examples demonstrate declaring a single JSON array as a variable and using OPENJSON to open it (e.g. [How to read field name with space in Json using OPENJSON in SQL Server 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345458/how-to-read-field-name-with-space-in-json-using-openjson-in-sql-server-2016)). I'd like to know how to actually build this into a database query.

Example structure of database table:

Table: HELP_INFO

| UID | ID | JSON |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45745 | JSON varchar - example below |
| 2 | 45745 | JSON varchar - example below |
| 3 | 82567 | JSON varchar - example below |

Example structure of the JSON

```
Example 1
    {"source":"XYZ",
     "source_info":{
         "type":"need_help",
         "help_info":{     
                "questions":50, 
                "details":[{"floatv":0.42,"name":"Tom"},{"floatv":1.08,"name":"Dick"},{"floatv":1.2,"name":"Harry"}]}}}

Example 2
    {"source":"XYZ",
     "source_info":{
         "type":"need_help",
         "help_info":{     
                "questions":12, 
                "details":[{"floatv":2.0,"name":"Donald"},{"floatv":0.4,"name":"Mickey"}]}}}
```

For each row in the table I need to open the "details" list in the JSON and extract all of the "name" values. The items in the details list always have the same keys, but the number of items in the list varies.

How would I write a query to do this, getting the source JSON values and their ID from rows on the HELP_INFO table?

Desired output:

| UID | NAMES |
| --- | --- |
| 45745 | Tom Dick Harry |
| 45745 | Donald Mickey |
| 82567 | Other names |

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `OPENJSON()` call with the appropriate `path` to access the nested `$.source_info.help_info.details` JSON array and `STRING_AGG()` to aggregate the names:

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 45745, '{"source":"XYZ",
     "source_info":{
         "type":"need_help",
         "help_info":{     
                "questions":50, 
                "details":[{"floatv":0.42,"name":"Tom"},{"floatv":1.08,"name":"Dick"},{"floatv":1.2,"name":"Harry"}]}}}')
) v (UID, ID, JSON)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   ID, 
   NAMES = (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(JSON_VALUE([value], '$.name'), ' ') 
             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key]))
      FROM OPENJSON(JSON, '$.source_info.help_info.details')
   )
FROM Data
```

Comment: Unbelievable! Great solution and ridiculously fast. Thank you so much, if would have taken me a long time to get there.

Comment: That `CONVERT(int, [key])` annoys me so much, I wish it was already an `int` and I wish it had a `unique` and ordering constraint, preventing the need for a `Sort` in the execution plan. Oh well, we can dream....

Comment: @Charlieface, I agree and I'm waiting for the new SQL Server 2022 JSON features ...